# networking platform to meet the IEC61850 sampled value requirements

Tags: pic, dsp, lvds

I've developed a linux based simulator of the IEC 61850 sampled value publisher, even with RT linux I still can't meet the requirement to publish a message with MTU =-1500, every 1uS on a PC platform. Someone suggested DSP chips, I really a fish out of water in the field, can someone suggest a DSP chip that can run linux and be able to meet the processing and network requirements.

Comment: A bit more background would be welcome. Eg.:  IEC 61850 sampled value publisher ? What interfaces do you use? What data size? How far are you of from the required result?

Comment: The shortest supported Ethernet frame is 64 bytes, resulting in 512 bits. This is disregarding tcp/ip, preamble, postamble and interframe gap. Sending 512 bits each microsecond requires 512 mb/s, at least gigabit Ethernet and an interface that can fully use that bandwidth. I'm not surprised that you can't reach your set goal.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the requirements for IEC 61850 Sampled Value transmission. It is possible that you could create a configuration file which demands a sample rate of 1 MHz, for a dataset that approaches 1500 bytes - but this is clearly unrealistic in practice.

There is a suggested (but not standardised) format for SV, IEC 61850-9-2 "LE" (Lite Edition), which is used by several hardware vendors. This includes up to four voltage and four current samples, and ends with a packet size of about 126 bytes. It is suggested to sample at 80 samples per nominal cycle for protection applications, so for a 50 Hz power system this means 4000 packets per second.

This equates to about 4 Mbps, per SV stream. If you are simulating the packet contents, then time synchronisation is likely not important in this case, so you shouldn't even need a real-time platform - a PC should be capable to generating several SV streams fast enough.

If of any use, I created a program which can be used to generate mock SV data: https://github.com/stevenblair/rapid61850

Comment: Thanks StevenBlair, I'm only seeing your response months later after I have seen your solution. Many thanks

Comment: Hi @sblair, I was wondering if you could throw a look at [this related thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/386030/4883) if you get a chance? Your repository is really helpful, but all samples I've found online use static SCL configuration which cannot be modified, so I don't understand how an actual IED gets the configuration from SCL config tools?