# Transfering configuration to IEDs using IEC 61850

Tags: protection, standard, automation

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but since I don't have much experience with [IEC 61850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61850) compliant devices, I am having trouble creating the "big picture" of how the whole system is being configured in practice.

Specifically, I don't understand how the devices which transmit data GOOSE or SV (without mentioning MMS in their datasheets) use the [Substation Configuration Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substation_Configuration_Language) (SCL) in practice, i.e. I cannot seem to find the exact part which mandates how the configuration is transferred to actual devices.

Can somebody clarify which part of the standard describes this? Are these files transmitted over FTP, or over custom vendor (proprietary) protocols, or does MMS provide a way to transmit SCL files in a standardized manner?

Comment: Go to the bottom of your link and click on references such as "Detailed Introduction to IEC 61850".

Comment: . IEC 61850 supports both FTP and MMS file transfer.  IEC TC 57

Comment: with IEC 62351 Security with big picture connections to something like 30,000 points and to 250 IEDs

Comment: @Andyaka: thanks, I read one of those pdf-s, and this is what I wanted to confirm: i.e. [the document you mentioned](http://seclab.illinois.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/iec61850-intro.pdf) states (slide 55) that "IED Configurator is a *manufacturer-specific* tool used to import or export SCL files and load IED configuration into the IED", so I was slightly surprised that the transfer of the configuration file wasn't also explicitly covered by the standard; i.e. you can manage multiple independent IEDs using IEC 61850, but you will still have to use separate tools to upload to each one?

Comment: If you can transfer data and the target has a bootloader capable of interpreting data as program information then you can transfer the full program to run on the target so, transferring a config file should be easy peazy.

Comment: @Andyaka: I am not saying that I cannot think of a way to transfer data to a device or create a custom tool for that, my question was whether there was a standard protocol for doing this, since 61850 standards seeks to remove differences between different vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standardised configuration process is defined in part IEC 61850-6 (along with the SCL itself). In summary:

- Each device should have an IED Capability Description (ICD) file, possibly generated by the IED online, or provided by the vendor.
- A software tool should be used to manage and combine multiple ICD files into the full SCD file, and set up things like GOOSE and SV communications between IEDs.
- Each IED should be configured with the full SCD file. It is possible to transfer files using MMS, but I think it is vendor-specific how the IED is configured from the SCD file.

Comment: Thanks! I understood the part about IED providing a "template" ICD and then getting SCD from the configurator software. But if I understood correctly: simple merging units will in practice get their configuration using proprietary tools?

Comment: Yes. But a merging unit is also a special case which has an established guideline implementation ("9-2LE") - because the dataset is pre-defined and relatively simple, a merging unit may not require configuration from SCD at all.

Answer (score 1):

To understand big picture of IEC 61850 please first read IEC 61850-7-1. There you will find main concepts explained. Details are in other parts.
To get the understanding of configuration, see IEC 61850-6 related to SCL.
Point of IEC 61850 is to provide mutual understanding akka interoperability between devices of different purpose and from different vendors. So, you could have multivendor system because it was more economical, and still operating in space and time (as a system and through asset life cycle).
SCL as a language provides means to establish device ID with all bits and piece (IED capability description file icd) and means to create intercorrelation between devices in the system (device <> MU, device <> device, device <> gateway etc) in scd (system configuration decsription) file.
Tried to be as much as possible general in story. Hope my fellow colleagues from IEC TC57 won't be to harsh to this explanation.
If more details needed please just ask.

In addition to your comment:
IEC 61850 is standardizing communication portion of one PAC system. So there is still some parts related to specific behavior to be defined locally in device. With IEC 61850 SCL on system level you can configure control blocks for GOOSE (virtual wire), SV (digital measurements), Reporting and Log (mechanisms for transfer toward HMIs, Gateways etc), assign IP address, create containers (DataSets) to be driven by abovementioned Control Blocks. And that is additional layer to enable interoperability and system configuration. In ideal world, you can transfer SCL file and IED should be able to work with it. But, because IEDs should always work as per vendor specification - they are not willing to allow loading of configuration without prior local validation. So they ask you to import SCL file, they will find their device in it, validate SCL configuration, merge it with local non IEC 61850 configuration and load it into IED. So, you can find simpler devices for which SCL config would be sufficient for operation but for more complex - you need ICT (IED Configuration tool) to validate, merge and load device with IEC 61850 configuration.

Comment: Thanks, my question was actually more related to the actual way the description file is transferred to devices from *multiple different vendors*. Since this file format is standardized, I was wondering if there was a standard way of transferring this information around? From what I've seen the format itself is standardized, but to configure each individual device, you need to open a tool from each manufacturer and configure them in advance manually.

Comment: SCT (system configuration tool) is not able to load all types of devices (different vendors), unless you have single-vendor solution. And that is not standardized because vendors are not in favor of this idea.